# How to add android like toast in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In android we can add toast directly.
Is their any method to add similar toast in iOS?

I created the transparent view to use as toast but for multiple text sizes i have to create more than one view.

Comment: Here are Many : https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=toast

Comment: what else you need with android here, kindly update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There is no Android type Toast control available in iOS.**

If you want to use something like it, you need to customise UIView with UILabel, or use some already created Toast type component, like below:

[Android Type Toast custom](https://github.com/Jameszjhe/METoast)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function to display toast message in iOS. Just create the extension on the view and call this method with the message.

**Swift 4**

```
extension UIView {

    func displayToast(_ message : String) {

        guard let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate, let window = delegate.window else {
            return
        }
        if let toast = window.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UILabel && $0.tag == -1001 }) {
            toast.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        let toastView = UILabel()
        toastView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
        toastView.textColor = UIColor.white
        toastView.textAlignment = .center
        toastView.font = UIFont(name: "Font-name", size: 17)
        toastView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        toastView.text = message
        toastView.numberOfLines = 0
        toastView.alpha = 0
        toastView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        toastView.tag = -1001

        window.addSubview(toastView)

        let horizontalCenterContraint: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: toastView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: window, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        let widthContraint: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: toastView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: (self.frame.size.width-25) )

        let verticalContraint: [NSLayoutConstraint] = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(>=200)-[toastView(==50)]-68-|", options: [.alignAllCenterX, .alignAllCenterY], metrics: nil, views: ["toastView": toastView])

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalCenterContraint, widthContraint])
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(verticalContraint)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            toastView.alpha = 1
        }, completion: nil)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(3), execute: {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
                toastView.alpha = 0
            }, completion: { finished in
                toastView.removeFromSuperview()
            })
        })
    }
}
```

usage:

just call `view.displayToast("Hello World")` from UIViewController

Comment: That's the best answer so far, since it adds a toast, which survives view switches. Having made it Swift 4 like and let it disappear, once a new toast is posted. Will add this as answer

Comment: Meanwhile I have improved it a bit (made it ready to remove an existing toast, to adapt to the textsize etc.) I will post the new version soon

Comment: Suhit Patil, @decades, can you please help me out how to bring toast on keypad when keypad appear. I need to show toast on bottom of screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) to show a toast like android. After adding [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) you can display a toast by this way

```
        let progressHUD = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
        progressHUD.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.text
        progressHUD.detailsLabel.text = "Your message here"
        progressHUD.margin = 10.0
        progressHUD.offset.y = 150.0
        progressHUD.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        progressHUD.removeFromSuperViewOnHide = true
        progressHUD.hide(animated: true, afterDelay: 3.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://github.com/scalessec/Toast) is best library I used for showing Toast in iOS apps same as android.

It also has `pod` support and pod name is `pod 'Toast'`

And implementation is so simple like

```
#import <UIView+Toast.h>
```

in your `ViewController` and then following line wherever you want to show it

```
[self.view makeToast:@"YOUR TOAST MESSAGE" duration:TOAST_TIMEOUT position:TOAST_CENTER];
```

Value for above keys are

```
#define TOAST_TOP @"CSToastPositionTop"
#define TOAST_CENTER @"CSToastPositionCenter"
#define TOAST_BOTTOM @"CSToastPositionBottom"
#define TOAST_TIMEOUT 2.0
```

Comment: No, it is not. You will notice once you switch a view with a toast open... Best solution (of all) see Suit below.

Comment: @decades Even toasts in android persists when you switch screens. And we can REMOVE toast before navigating to the screen.

Answer (score 1):

there is no **ThostView** in iOS. we Can custom are use 3rd party libraries. 
follow this link -

- https://github.com/scalessec/Toast-Swift

Answer (score 0):

There is a 3rd party library that supports customizable toast notification with single line of code. Here is a simple example of it:

```
import Toast_Swift

...

// basic usage
self.view.makeToast("This is a piece of toast")

// toast with a specific duration and position
self.view.makeToast("This is a piece of toast", duration: 3.0, position: .top)
```

[Toast Swift library](https://github.com/scalessec/Toast-Swift)

Or else,

If you want to implement by your own. Use below code.

```
let toastLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 150, self.view.frame.size.height-100, 300, 35))
                    toastLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                    toastLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                    toastLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;
                    self.view.addSubview(toastLabel)
                    toastLabel.text = "hello man..."
                    toastLabel.alpha = 1.0
                    toastLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
                    toastLabel.clipsToBounds  =  true
                    UIView.animateWithDuration(4.0, delay: 0.1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {

                        toastLabel.alpha = 0.0

                        })
```

Comment: This library doesn't work if the holding view disappears in favour of a new view. The toast disappears too. This is not Android like. The only solution is to make the toast a child of the main window, not the view. But this is a problem of nearly all Toast libs out...

Answer (score 0):

An attempt to make Suhit Pal's answer above Swift 4 like with a way to remove an existing Toast once a new appears

```
extension UIView {

    private static var toastView: UILabel? = nil

    func displayToast(message : String, duration: Double? = 3.0) -> Void {
        if UIView.toastView != nil {
            UIView.toastView!.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        UIView.toastView = UILabel()
        UIView.toastView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
        UIView.toastView!.textColor = UIColor.white
        UIView.toastView!.textAlignment = .center
        UIView.toastView!.font = UIFont(name: "Font-name", size: 17)
        UIView.toastView!.layer.masksToBounds = true
        UIView.toastView!.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        UIView.toastView!.text = message
        UIView.toastView!.numberOfLines = 0
        UIView.toastView!.alpha = 0
        UIView.toastView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window!
        window?.addSubview(UIView.toastView!)

        let horizontalCenterContraint : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: UIView.toastView!, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: window, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let widthContraint: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: UIView.toastView!, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: (self.frame.size.width-25) )
        let verticalContraint: [NSLayoutConstraint] = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(>=200)-[loginView(==50)]-68-|", options: [.alignAllCenterX, .alignAllCenterY], metrics: nil, views: ["loginView": UIView.toastView!])

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalCenterContraint, widthContraint])
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(verticalContraint)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            UIView.toastView!.alpha = 1
        }, completion: nil)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + duration!) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
                UIView.toastView!.alpha = 0
            }, completion: { (_) in
                UIView.toastView!.removeFromSuperview()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my latest version of this. It allows to cancel an existing toast by just pushing a new. It also allows to provide an optional "reverseColors" parameter, which writes white on black instead default black on white. The toast adapts to the text size with a little margin left and right.

```
extension UIView {

    private static var toastView: UILabel? = nil
    private static var toastViewCancelTask : DispatchWorkItem?

    func displayToast(message : String, duration: Double, reverseColors: Bool? = false) -> Void {
        if UIView.toastView != nil {
            UIView.toastView!.removeFromSuperview()
            UIView.toastViewCancelTask?.cancel()
        }


        UIView.toastView = UILabel()
        UIView.toastViewCancelTask = DispatchWorkItem {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
                UIView.toastView!.alpha = 0
            }, completion: { (_) in
                UIView.toastView!.removeFromSuperview()
            })
        }

        let toastView = UIView.toastView!
        print(message)

        if reverseColors != nil && reverseColors! {
            toastView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
            toastView.textColor = UIColor.white
        }
        else {
            toastView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
            toastView.textColor = UIColor.black
        }
        toastView.textAlignment = .center
        toastView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
        toastView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        toastView.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        toastView.text = message
        toastView.numberOfLines = 0
        toastView.alpha = 0
        toastView.sizeToFit()
        toastView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let width = toastView.frame.size.width +  100 > self.frame.size.width ? self.frame.size.width - 100 : toastView.frame.size.width + 100

        let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window!
        window?.addSubview(toastView)

        let horizontalCenterContraint : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: toastView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: window, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let widthContraint: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: toastView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: width )
        let verticalContraint: [NSLayoutConstraint] = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(>=200)-[loginView(==50)]-30-|", options: [.alignAllCenterX, .alignAllCenterY], metrics: nil, views: ["loginView": toastView])

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalCenterContraint, widthContraint])
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(verticalContraint)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            toastView.alpha = 0.8
        }, completion: nil)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + duration , execute: UIView.toastViewCancelTask!)
    }

}
```