# Show popup message (toast) from screenshot with my text

Tags: ios, uikit, ios14

How can i show this popup message? With my text instead "Safari pasted from VK"

[image]

Comment: Not the top answer, but check Suhit Patil's answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41422251/how-to-add-android-like-toast-in-ios which is written in Swift 4, but I tried and it still works on Swift 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Toast (as it's called on Android platform) is used by UIKit14 but not available to developers.

You have to develop it by yourself or get a pod like [SwiftEntryKit](https://github.com/huri000/SwiftEntryKit)

Answer (score 0):

If You can't write it by yourself try to use and customize some pod like [SwiftEntryKit](https://github.com/huri000/SwiftEntryKit)

Comment: Yes, my custom solution used in my project now.